# Cloud build failing on git submodules

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, continuous-integration, git-submodules

I have a Unity project in a git repo hosted on VSTS with submodules, I've integrated it the git repo with Unity cloud build.

When Cloud Build tires to do a build it seems to go fine checking everything out until it reaches the modules, it hangs on the line '328: Cloning into 'Assets/MySubmodule'... and just waits there for about an hour before the build fails for taking too long.

I get an error sometimes that goes like:

Username for 'https://mycompany.visualstudio.com': Clone of 'https://mycompany.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/mysubmodulerepopath' into submodule path 'Assets/mysubmodule' failed

I'm thinking the issue might be that the submodules are not being referenced as ssh links but directly as https, is there some work around or something I need to do to get them to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by updating the submodule git urls to use ssh

Comment: That is one way indeed. +1 My solution did not involve changing tracked files.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking the issue might be that the submodules are not being referenced as ssh links but directly as https

Then, you can cloning again, this time using ssh.
First, type:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Then clone your repo again (`git clone --recursive`)